# Unwanted toast?

Tags: android, toast

In my app I'm using few external libraries. Some of them needs **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission but it is optional. I dont want it so I added to my manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="remove" />
```

Problem is one of libs (I dont know which one) displays a toast :

> "Missing permission : android. permission.WRITE.EXTERNAL.STORAGE".

I don't want it - app works totally fine and I don't want to push users to add permission that is not needed. Libraries are not open source so I cant check it. Do you know how can I check which library displays this toast ? I really want to block, or remove it :)

Comment: check your lib code. Search the toast message and If its possible to edit then try it.

Comment: Its not possible. Thats the problem :/

Comment: Which lib you are using .

Comment: I think it could be Helpshift

Comment: Ok. What toast you want to hide?

Comment: "Missing permission : android. permission.WRITE.EXTERNAL.STORAGE".

Comment: Where are you getting this error ?

Comment: after launching the app so I think it could be something with data parsing

Comment: In your project, search for if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(RuntimePermissionsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE.EXTERNAL.STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)  . YOu will most probably find this toast inside this condition which you can comment out.

Answer (score 0):

you can try **ctrl+shift+f** which will open a global project search and search for "toast", this will get you all the toast messages, then remove the one you don't need, though this might required you to edit the code in the library, for which i'm not sure if you'd have the permission.

Other workaround is to check the library and see where the toast is getting triggered and try counter-acting the trigger.

Comment: I cant find that toast using "find" option. I tried it.

Comment: Try changing the option to directory, and select your app directory

Answer (score 0):

find the toast text in project using `Ctrl+Shift+F`

Comment: I cant find that toast using "find" option. I tried it.

Comment: @Bartos can you provide the link of library?

Answer (score 0):

Run the app while connected to the Ide, you may find some useful infos in the logcat and maybe identify the library requesting the unwanted permission.